# Is it safe to cast void pointer to char pointer pointer

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Just wondering if it's safe to cast like this:

```
char **cpp;
// ... allocation and what not 
void *vp = (void *)cpp;
// ...
cpp = (char **)vp;
```

should a void ** be used or is void * fine? This works on a couple of my boxes without issue but was wondering if it could cause problems on certain systems.

Comment: Why throw away type info here?  It's there for a good reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cast is always safe, dereferencing it is safe as long as the pointer is valid.
The only case where you'd use a `void **` is when you plan to dereference it to get a `void *`.

However, unless you do pointer arithmetics it won't really matter. As you can see on http://codepad.org/UcZUA0UL it works fine no matter if you use `void*` or `void **`. Before you actually use the pointer you are going to cast it back to `char **` anyway - so it is never dereferenced while it's `void`-ish.

Answer (score 3):

The casting (and usage afterwards) from `void*`, if the original pointer was `char **`.

You shouldn't use `void**`.