# Will a void* always have the same representation as a char*?

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer

Will a `void*` always have the same representation as a `char*` ?

**Details:**

I want to work with a variadic function that takes char*'s terminated by a `(char*)0` like so:

```
int variadic(char*, ...); //<-prototype
variadic("foo", "bar", (char*)0); //<- usage
```

I wanted to replace `(char*)0` with `NULL`, but judging from 
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf's:

> 66) The macro NULL is defined in  (and other headers) as a
>   null pointer constant; see 7.19.
>
> 3 An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an
>   expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant. 66)
>   If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the
>   resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare
>   unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

I can't, because in the `variadic` context, I absolutely need a `char*` and a plain `0` is unacceptable.

If I defined:

```
#define NIL (void*)0 /*<= never a plain 0*/
```

would it be legal for me to use it to terminate my `variadic(char*,...)`?

Comment: A `void*` is always implicitly convertible to any other (data) pointer type, that's a given by the `C` standard.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Yes, but that only matters *if* there is a conversion being done.

Comment: Did you check how the `NULL` macro is defined in your implementation? It typically **is** `((void *)0)`. But if you pass `0` to a variadic function, it will be passed as `int`, which is not what you want. So you have to cast it anyway.

Comment: Also, the part 'a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.' means that whatever address you take, of a valid object or function, is never 0.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Variadic functions are a bit different, as the caller does not know if (and which) pointer types are expected.

Comment: @StoryTeller: With respect to the standard a _null pointer_ is not identical with address `0x0`! That is one of the inconsistencies in C. And one reason C++11 finally introduced the `nullptr` keyword and e.g. Pascal, Modula, etc. have `NIL`.

Comment: @Olaf I have, and it's ((void*)0) in all the implementations I've seen. But what an implementation does should be irrelevant to a language-lawyer-tagged question.

Comment: @PSkocik: See the last sentence. (Maybe I should have added "... to be on the safe side"). That whole `NULL`/`0` stuff is broken by design since early versions of C. I always wonder why then did not follow the Pascal (Algol?)-Trail and provided that as special keyword.

Comment: @Olaf, yes variadic functions are different, but unless my memory fails me, pointer types should fall under a set of argument conversions. So it is a matter of how `NULL` is defined here (as you said). You are right that the standard doesn't guarantee two null pointers of different types will share a value, but I do believe a the quote in the OP makes an exception for `(void*)0`

Comment: @Olaf Looks like simply mandating `#define NULL ((void*)0)` and disallowing a plain `0` would fix the problem.

Comment: @PSkocik: It does not! You still can do `int *p = 0x0;` or any other integer expression evaluating to `0`. And - strictly speaking - you cannot dereference address `0x0`, just because of the above. Not to forget the compiler cannot even warn about such assignments. Remember there is no requirement for a _null pointer_ to have a bit-representation of all bits zero.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to cast void pointer to char pointer pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555320/is-it-safe-to-cast-void-pointer-to-char-pointer-pointer)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: It is not the same, because null pointers are special as are variadic function parameters.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc It's a distinct question. Casts force conversions. No conversions other than a couple of implicit promotions will be performed on the parameters of a variadic function. The promoted passed types must match what the function takes with `va_arg` or undefined behavior ensues. Whether a cast would be legal is irrelevant to that unless that cast is the same as the implicit promotion.

Comment: This question in the title is necessary, but not sufficient, to determine whether `va_arg(char *)` will successfully read a `void *` argument. For example, perhaps they have the same alignment and representation, but an implementation passes them in different registers.  I'd suggest editing the title and first paragraph to be closer to the "real" question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

C11, §6.2.5, ¶28 (draft [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) says:

> **A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment
>   requirements as a pointer to a character type.** 48) Similarly, pointers
>   to qualiﬁed or unqualiﬁed versions of compatible types shall have the
>   same representation and alignment requirements.

(emphasis mine).

Comment: That's actually an interesting requirement. So on an architecture where code pointers are larger than data pointer pointers this requirement forces char pointers to be padded. Intel 80C51 is such an example since it has 128 bytes of ram but 4 KB of program rom. (Though this is a modified Harvard architecture which allows reading program rom as data so a unified data pointer still needs more room)

Comment: @poizan42 I thought function pointers and data pointers were treated differently in C, explicitly to handle the case you mention, where code pointers are larger.

Comment: POSIX (but *not* the C language standard) requires code pointers to be losslessly convertible to `void*` in order for the `dlsym` function to work.

Comment: @CortAmmon I think you are right, code pointers does not need to be convertible to void*. What might be the interesting part here is then that the C standard does not specify a universal pointer type (though I guess such a thing could be inefficient or pointless on certain platform, e.g. straight Hardvard architectures where you can't read from any code pointers anyways)

Comment: Note that this is insufficient to permit `void *` to be passed *as an untyped argument* where the callee is expecting `char *`, or vice versa.  (Per MSalters' answer, there's additional rules in the definition of `va_arg` that close the gap.)  And this was *not* a requirement in C90.

Comment: @poizan42 To be clear:  "where code pointers are larger than data pointer pointers this requirement forces char pointers to be padded" is not specified by C.  Pointers to a function can be wider than `void*`.

Comment: @dan04: That only applies to function pointers obtainable via `dlsym()`. In principle, other function pointer values might not be losslessly convertible to `void*`.

Answer (score 11):

It's specifically allowed to access a `void*` argument using `va_arg(args, char*)` and vice versa, not just for the null pointer.

See also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_arg

Comment: This was added in C99.  In C90, you are *not* allowed to do this.

Comment: @zwol: To be honest, that's a quarter century old.

Comment: @MSalters And yet, C89 is still the default for what I'd guess is an absolute majority of C compilers.

Comment: @zwol I'd say that in C90 it was intended that this be allowed, but not specified clearly enough. It's hard to come up with a reason why the C90 standard would have the line "A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type. " if not for this purpose.  Prior to standardization, the language didn't have `void *`; it seems clear to me that the intent is that for un-prototyped function arguments (including K&R style ones, as well as the variadic part of a prototyped variadic function), `char *` and `void *` are interchangeable