# How do I launch a Python program with an empty argv?

Tags: python, subprocess

The problem I am having is that after running the program, it errors out saying that my argv contains 1 entries and it needs it to be 0

```py
import subprocess
args = ['/challenge/embryoio_level75']
subprocess.run(args)
```

Comment: That should do it. What's the problem?

Comment: Pay attention to the fact that this is an absolute path.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146 and https://xyproblem.info and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. What happens when you run the code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen? What actually is your question?

Comment: How is this question not fitting stackoverflow's scope?

Comment: The problem i am having is that after running the program it errors out saying that my argv contains 1 entries and it needs it to be 0

Answer (score 11):

Update from [rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici)'s comment:

Apparently this hack is possible too:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run([], executable="/path/to/executable")
```

---

Python, C/C++ and other languages are reserving the first value (`argv[0]`) as the value of the executable that's currently running and is set automatically.

For Python the [`sys.argv[0]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) would be one of:

- `-c`
- the script name
- `""` (empty string)

You can test it with:

```sh
exec -a "" python -c 'import sys;print(sys.argv[0]);input("pause")'
exec -a "" python <file>
exec -a "" python  # then print sys.argv[0] manually
```

Python itself is using [`os.execvpe()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execvpe) under the hood for process spawning which is a Linux/Posix function. This function prohibits empty `args` parameter which is then passed to the child process itself.

A very simple C program for just printing the `argv[0]` is below. Alternatively `import sys;print(sys.argv[0])` but spawning with `python -c '<code>'` or `python <file>` may add unnecessary params, therefore I use C to prevent the noise.

```c
// gcc -o a.out main.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Spawn a child process with Python directly with `os.execvpe()`

```py
import os
os.execvpe("./a.out", [], {})  # error
os.execvpe("./a.out", ["-"], {})  # but this works
```

It'll still give you the first argument in the child process, it requires you to define the value, so you can use anything instead of the executable's path.

Even using [`os.execl()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execl) ([like in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49817618/5994041)) and similar ones are handled so they prevent you not passing the value, unfortunately, even though [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) allows such a behavior.

> The various exec* functions take a list of arguments for the new program loaded into the process. In each case, the first of these arguments is passed to the new program as its own name rather than as an argument a user may have typed on a command line. For the C programmer, this is the argv[0] passed to a program’s main(). For example, os.execv('/bin/echo', ['foo', 'bar']) will only print bar on standard output; foo will seem to be ignored. ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#process-management))

The funniest part is, that CPython's implementation uses [`_execvpe()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2a38e1ab65cb28af3babda17f6ad3f8e514a7455/Lib/os.py#L588) whose exec funcs are "undefined" for a normal lookup. It's probably hot-patched similarly like the builtins are created, from C and directly by manipulating the module's `globals` storage.

If we dig a bit deeper, we can find the CPython's implementation preventing us to hack around [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/443b308fee088e21bbf472c376c5c9e3648f916c/Modules/clinic/posixmodule.c.h#L2146).

There's another way and that's by directly utilizing the `unistd.h`'s [`exec`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) either by wrapping is as a library (e.g. with [Cython](https://cython.org/) or [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html)) or by passing `shell=True` to subprocess and calling it from a shell:

```py
# int execl(const char *pathname, const char *arg, ..., /*, (char *) NULL */);
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
lib.execl("./a.out", None)
```

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["exec", "-a", "", "./a.out"], shell=True)
```

it'll still create the first `argv`, but it'll at least be empty string unlike in CPython.

That's however, Linux specific. It might work on MacOS though. For Windows you'll need to check [`CreateProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) probably the `lpApplicationName` parameter.

---

Extra: With CPython 3.10 you can access [`sys.orig_argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=argv#sys.orig_argv) which will pull the same value that would be passed into the C code above. Notice the difference between the `orig_argv` and `argv`:

```py
$ docker run -it -u 0:0 python:3.10 bash
root@a801e79a4264:/# exec -a "" python
Python 3.10.2 (main, Feb  8 2022, 04:44:29) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.orig_argv
[]
>>> sys.argv
['']
>>>
```

As mentioned by rici, it'll be a bit problematic achieving something reasonable with the interpreter's binary, so embedding will help with that. One of the embedding types is quite simple, just utilize [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io):

```py
$ docker run -it -u 0:0 python:3.10 bash
root@149accac00c8:/# exec -a "" python main.py 
# import sys;print(sys.argv, sys.orig_argv)
['main.py'] ['', 'main.py']
```

vs

```sh
$ docker run -it -u 0:0 python:3.10 bash
root@21a9fed751b8:/# pip install pyinstaller
root@21a9fed751b8:/# pyinstaller --onefile main.py
root@21a9fed751b8:/# bash  # spawn subprocess to prevent exec closing the window
root@21a9fed751b8:/# exec -a "" dist/main 
[''] []
```

Comment: You can run a subprocess with an empty argv array rather more simply using `subprocess.run([], executable="/path/to/executable")`. Your C program will report an empty list. However, a Python program won't, because `sys.argv[0]` is not `argv[0]`. (I don't know if this will work on Windows but it will certainly work on any Unix-like implementation.)

Comment: @rici damn, it's the little things! :D I should have thought about that before digging through the C code.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that Python 3.10 added [`sys.orig_argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=argv#sys.orig_argv), which is supposedly "The list of the original command line arguments passed to the Python executable." However, that doesn't help either because the original command-line to run a Python script actually runs some Python executable, and the shebang command emulation loses the original `argv[0]`. So I think that the only way to actually see the original `argv[0]` would be to write a C program which embeds a Python interpreter.

Comment: @rici I've added an example with PyInstaller to show the diff between non-embedded and embedded values. :)